# Adding image to login page in cakephp

Tags: html, css, cakephp

I'm creating a login page in cakephp. Instead of writing "Login", I thought of showing an image. This is how I tried:

```
<br>
<div class="index large-4 medium-4 large-offset-4 medium-offset-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
        <h2 class="text-center"><img src="img/cake.icon.png" /></h2>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('email'); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password')); ?>
            <?= $this->Form->submit('Login', array('class' => 'button')); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above layout, I tried to add a image `logo.png` instead of showing "Login". But, the image did not load. I've placed the image in webroot/img/logo.png. But, the image is not loading. What's wrong with this? What should I change or add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the document: [HtmlHelper::image](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image)

Try this:

```
<h2 class="text-center">
  <?php echo $this->Html->image('logo.png'); ?>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the src to use logo.png instead of cake.icon.png

```
<img src="img/logo.png" />
```

Comment: to solve this problem, you need to identify why the image is not being loaded by the page. make sure that you can access the image via http://yourUrl /img/logo.png - if you can load it in a browser, press f12 when loading your page and see what status code is returned when the page attempts to load the image